# Get file extension in client side with Fine-Uploader

Tags: fine-uploader

I am using Basic Fine-Uploader.

Is there any way to get the file extension before uploading it in client side when I select the it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`getName`](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#getName) API method to retrieve the name for a file when you have its `id`.

Keep in mind a few caveats, though:

- In iOS all images are named "image.jpg"
- Files submitted via drag and drop and paste are going to be named "blob" -- no extension, just blob.
- Blobs are named "misc_data" by default by Fine Uploader. ()This can be changed via the `blobs.defaultName` option, and/or via the `setName` API method)

Comment: Just a quick correction: blobs are named "misc_data" by default by Fine Uploader.  This can be changed via the `blobs.defaultName` option, and/or via the `setName` API method.